# CodeIgniter File Upload - Fat models skin controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'd like to ask a question please.

I have inside my model a method that holds both file uploading and image manipulation. The code works fine, but the only problem is I can't figure out how to get the upload error back in the controller in order to pass it to the view and display it to the user.

This is the code in my model:

```
class Foo_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function do_upload(){
        $id = intval($this->input->post('id'));
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => './uploads/files/',
            'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png',
            'max_size'      =>  '2048',
            'max_width'     =>  '800',
            'max_heigth'    =>  '300',
            'overwrite'     =>  true,
            'file_name'     =>  'file_'.$id, // e.g. file_10.jpg
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file') ) {

            return $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
            // file uploaded successfully
            // now lets create some thumbs
            $upload_file = $this->upload->data();
            if ($upload_file['is_image']) {
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $upload_file['file_name'];
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 75;
                $config['height'] = 50;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                $this->image_lib->resize();
            }

            // uploading and resizing was done
            return $upload_file;
            // return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Code in my controller

```
public function upload(){

    $this->foo_model->do_upload();
    // need to get the upload error (if any occured) or the upload data
    // how can I get them back from function of the model?

    $this->load->view('form_upload', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `return` errors from `Model` method so hold returned data in variable and check that is `error` or `file_data`

```
public function upload(){

    $upload_data = $this->foo_model->do_upload();
    //upload data will be return in array format
    if(is_array($upload_data)){
      $data['upload_file_info'] = $upload_data
    }else{ /*error as string so if not array then always error*/
      $data['error']  = $upload_data;
    }

    $this->load->view('form_upload', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hi Girish, thanks for your reply! I haven't found the time yet to test your code, but I'll tell you as soon as I do. I have a question though.. Basicly the $configs for upload and resize hold the business logic, right? so do I only need to push the $configs inside the model and if so how can I make the options dynamic?